# Is out there anything that is for s-expressions what XPATH is for XML?

Tags: xml, xpath, lisp, s-expression

I am looking for a common-lisp impl if possible.
(Also, I dont want to convert sexp to XML and use xpath on the result.)

Comment: What is `@` equivalent you would accept for s-expressions?

Comment: And why `car`, `cdr`, `position`, `assoc` (I just realized that an assoc list can be considered as attributes), `equal` and so on are not enough to select from s-expression everything you want?

Comment: I just want a compact syntax. Eventually i will try it as you suggest, if i dont find anything. Propably implement my own syntax in lisp but i just wanted to know if anyone has made anything on top of what you suggest, in order to provide an easier notation for navigating sexps

Comment: Are you looking for destructuring operations? Are you looking to transform the source objects and emit the transformation?

Comment: There are many ways you could represent a DOM with sexps, so whatever XPath implementation you use would have to be specific for that representation.  There are some hits for ["xpath" on CLiki](http://www.cliki.net/admin/search?words=xpath)

Comment: @seh : nothing fancy, just a dsl for selecting nodes by path name and by position in sexps in order to get the value. I ve already started to implement my own mini xpath-like notation and translate it to list manipulation calls like khachik suggested.

Comment: @Daniel: you are right, my mistake is that I silently considered the SXML project's type of representation to be what I meant in my head. Since it is the only representation of xml using sexps i came across.

Comment: @Daniel: On the other hand, I dont want to search a sexp that will necessarily represent a DOM. I am talking something more generic. Sexps dont have to represent a DOM. I want a compact syntax for navigating sexps. I dont imply that the sexps I will search can represent the XML Infoset. The only restriction on the search object of my "Navigating mini-DSL" is that it is an s-expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a bit late answer, but it seems http://www.cliki.net/spath is exactly what you look for.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [SSAX+SXML+SXPATH](http://ssax.sourceforge.net/)? It's Scheme rather than Common Lisp but that shouldn't hold you up for long.